# Commit Aggressive Member List is affecting surrounding code Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, I press `tab` to complete a word from the suggestion list.
This is causing the surrounding function to be replaced with the suggestion.
I would prefer it to simply complete the word inside the parentheses.

I have provided two screenshots highlighting the issue.
In these screenshots `FOO` is a macro, but the issue occurs with functions too:
e.g. `void Foo(bool value) {}`

My question is:
**What setting can I use to prevent completion from removing the surrounding macro/function?**

[image: Visual Studio suggests complete with true]

[image: Visual Studio completion erases surrounding macro]

Comment: The settings related to IntelliSense are very limited, and I think there may not be the setting you want.